# Lexical Error while running featuretoolsR

Tags: r, featuretools

In an effort to test the working of featuretools, I installed featuretoolsR through RStudio,and installed numpy and featuretools in Python.

However on trying to create an entitiy following error is coming

````
# Libs
library(featuretoolsR)
library(magrittr)

# Create some mock data
set_1 <- data.frame(key = 1:100, value = sample(letters, 100, T))
set_2 <- data.frame(key = 1:100, value = sample(LETTERS, 100, T))

# Create entityset
es <- as_entityset(set_1, index = "key", entity_id = "set_1", id = "demo")```

Error: lexical error: invalid char in json text.
                                       WARNING: The conda.compat modul
                     (right here) ------^

Kindly help in diagnosing and providing solution to same.
````

Comment: This seems to be bug. Try contacting the author at [github](https://github.com/magnusfurugard/featuretoolsR)

Answer (score 1):

The same warning happened to me after updating to conda version 4.6.11. I think the problem is generated because of the print statement at the end of the compat.py script. I know this is not a great fix but I accessed the compat.py file and removed the print statement:

```
print("WARNING: The conda.compat module is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.", file=sys.stderr)
```

The file should be located here: \Anaconda3\pkgs\conda-4.6.11-py37_0\Lib\site-packages\conda

I hope it helps.